# Databind Listview menu and submenu with click function

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I need a help 
 I need a simple app of windows store app c# to

--> **bind listview menu and submenu**

the values should pass from c# to xaml i cant figure it bind as well do onclick operation of it for example if i click ferrari the right side message show you selected ferrari

example below

```
  car                          < -- menu1
       ferrari                     <-- submenu 1 of menu1
       lambourgini                 <-- submenu 2 of menu1
  phone                       < -- menu2
       nokia                       <-- submenu 1 of menu2
       iphone                      <-- submenu 2 of menu2
```

if possible please post both xaml and c# code downloaded i am trying it for past one week like accordian i couldnt finish it can you provide a simple sample please

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should not build this from scratch but instead use the tree view control that comes with the WinRT XAML Toolkit. It's quite nice. And, free.

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com